# AutoML Training items limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, items, automl, google-mlkit

GCP AutoML Natural Language , training items limit is 1,000,000 items. I will need to increase that much more than 1 million, How do I do that? Is that done through GCP support is there any other option? I do not see that listed in edit quota.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a quota and a limit is that a limit **cannot** be adjusted, whereas you can request a quota increase. If I understand correctly the 1,000,000 training items is a [limit](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/quotas) for AutoML and thus cannot be changed.